# redhat: netbeans: g++: compiler options applied to linker

Tags: netbeans, linker, g++

I am using NetBeans under RedHat.  I have a couple of open projects that combine together to make a command line executable and a shared object "plugin".  There are two static libraries in the mix as well.  That is all fine and good.

I just noticed that when I "clean and build" the executable and the shared object that the compiler options are also expressed on the linker line. a la:

```
g++ -O2 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0   -c -g -Werror -DDEBUG -DDEBUG_2 -I/usr/include -I/usr/include/c++/4.4.7/x86_64-redhat-linux -I/usr/include/c++/4.4.7 -I../ITGUtilities -MMD -MP -MF "build/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/LocalCache.o.d" -o build/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/LocalCache.o LocalCache.cpp
```

then later in the compile line (edited for brevity):

```
g++ -O2 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -fPIC    -o dist/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/pam_plugin.so build/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/pam_plugin.o -L... -lpam -l... -shared -fPIC
g++: build/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/pam_plugin.o: linker input file unused because linking not done
```

I think I have a fairly generic set of project configs.  I did set the `-O2 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0` compiler options but there are no options supplied for the linker other than whatever defaults NetBeans applies.

For the executable and plugin projects I can go to `Properties > Linker > Additional Options` and expand the `[...]` to see what NB thinks it will apply.  That does not show the compile options but doing an actual build does apply them.

It is not doing the link step and I am assuming that is because of the compiler options.  This is weird.

ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not add `-c` option to the compiler options which says not to run the linker. It will be added as needed when just compiling anyway.

Comment: Doh! Thank you. That was exactly it.